# Weird behavior in Spring

Tags: spring

I am using Spring's `SmartFactoryBean` interface to create an object. This interface has a method `isEagerInit()` which as per documentation tells when to initialize the object returned from `getObject()` method of this interface. There is another method in this interface `isPrototype()` which tells the scope of the object in the spring container.

Now the weird behavior what I am noticing is with `isEagerInit()` method. If I return `true` from this method, I could see two instances of my object are getting created, which contradicts `isPrototype()` method.

Sample classes:

```
public class MyBean {
    public MyBean() {
        System.out.println("MyBean Instance created...");
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I am doing something...");
    }
}

public class MyBeanSmartFactoryBean implements SmartFactoryBean&lt;MyBean&gt; {
    @Override
    public boolean isPrototype() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEagerInit() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public MyBean getObject() throws Exception {
        return new MyBean();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return MyBean.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }
}

@Component("sample")
public class Sample {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myBeanSmartFactoryBean")
    private MyBean myBean;

    public void doSample() {
        System.out.println("Inside Sample; calling MyBean to doSomething...");
        myBean.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Spring config:

```
<bean id="myBeanSmartFactoryBean" class="com.demo.MyBeanSmartFactoryBean" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo" />
```

Test code

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml");

        final Sample sampleOne = (Sample) applicationContext.getBean("sample");
        sampleOne.doSample();

        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++");
        final Sample sampleTwo = (Sample) applicationContext.getBean("sample");
        sampleTwo.doSample();

        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++");
        final Sample sampleThree = (Sample) applicationContext.getBean("sample");
        sampleThree.doSample();
    }
}
```

**Output - 1 (when `isEagerInit()` returns `false`)**

```
MyBean Instance created...
Inside Sample; calling MyBean to doSomething...
I am doing something...
++++++++++++++++++++++
Inside Sample; calling MyBean to doSomething...
I am doing something...
++++++++++++++++++++++
Inside Sample; calling MyBean to doSomething...
I am doing something...
```

**Output - 1 (when `isEagerInit()` returns `true`)**

```
MyBean Instance created...
MyBean Instance created...
Inside Sample; calling MyBean to doSomething...
I am doing something...
++++++++++++++++++++++
Inside Sample; calling MyBean to doSomething...
I am doing something...
++++++++++++++++++++++
Inside Sample; calling MyBean to doSomething...
I am doing something...
```

Please notice the statement **MyBean Instance created...** appears twice.

Appreciate if someone can explain what is going on.

Thanks,

Niranjan

Comment: Eager init creates an instance as soon as possible. You also specified it not to be a singleton (`isSingleton` returns `false` ) so when needed a new instance is created. Basically your `isPrototype` and `isSingleton` method contradict each other.

Comment: No! To explain, these are not my methods; and the method `isSingleton()` tells if the object I am returning is a singleton object or not. This is same as Java Singleton. `isPrototype()` is related to Spring's bean scope. I agree they are confusing and I can clearly see why Spring guys created a sub interface of `FactoryBean`. I also understand how eager init works. But then, if through eager init an instance is already created why another instance is getting created up-on access?

Comment: Because `isSingleton` returns false! The object isn't a singleton so as soon as an instance is requested a new instance is created. `isSingleton` isn't the same as a java singleton! I suggest you enable TRACE logging for `org.springframework` and you will see the behavior as I described.

Comment: Hi Martin, making `isSingleton()` return `true` resolved the issue. However, I still feel the method names are not very clear. What I feel is, `isSingleton()` makes Spring cache the instance that is already created. With this method and `isPrototype()`, anybody can do the mistake I did. Why putting methods which can cause conflicts?

Comment: In general you should be using the `FactoryBean` interface and not the `SmartFactoryBean` interface. The latter is a special purpose mainly for internal use by the framework. The `isPrototype` method indicates if the return object should be considered a prototype or not, the `isSingleton` method indicates that this factorybean returns a single instance. In theory you can have a single instance which should itself be treated as a prototype.